# How to get value from mocked interface that has no get with Moq?

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I'm trying to write some tests for a specific interface using *Moq*. The values of the object that implements the interface are set by a class that we will call "controller" in this question.

Interface:

```
public interface ITestInterface
{
    int number {set;}
}
```

And my mock:

```
Mock<ITestInterface> myTestMock = new Mock<ITestInterface>();
```

To do the test, I expect the controller to set the number in the mocked class, but then i need to *get* the value to test it. Something like this:

```
Controller c = new Controller(myTestMock.Object);
c.Initialize(); //initialization will set number to something
Assert.AreEqual(myTestMock.number, 3);
```

Of course I get an error because I can't read that value, given that the interface does not have a "get" method.

**How can I setup a get for my mock without changing the interface?**

Comment: Instead of `Assert.AreEqual`, maybe you can use `myTestMock.VerifySet(x => x.number = 3);`

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo it will give me the same error "lacks a get accessor"

Comment: @Th0rndike - remove the `Assert` line. @Thariq is right `myTestMock.VerifySet(x => x.number = 3);` works. (Just tested it, as it was new to me, too). -- assuming `c.Initialize();` *really* sets the number. I even tried `myTestMock.VerifySet(x => x.number = 4);` and it failed the test, because it only recognized that it was set to 3, not 4.

Comment: OK! got it. I didn't get at first that "verifySet" meant that it's verifing that the value was set instead of that the value is a specific value and wrote it with an == operator. Thanks!!!!! (someone make it an answer...)

Comment: Beware though, if `c.Initialize()` sets `number` to `3` and *after that* sets it to something different, the test still passes. `Moq` probably just stores every call to `set` and `VerifySet` only checks if there was at least one call like `number = 3`.

Comment: ... seems like there is no way to tell `Moq` that the specified `setterExpression` should be the _last_ one called. So that's something that has to be kept in mind. -- (with the `Times` parameter, you can at least check how many times it was set to `3`...)

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan since you really seem to want to know, the value is going to end up in the frontend. The implementation of the interface is a webform, and this is an example of a pattern called MVP used to test webforms. The test is used to test (duh!) the controller of the page. But there could be other useful examples of a value with only a setter...

Answer (score 0):

Use your own implementation

```
public class FakeTestInterface : ITestInterface
{
    public int NumberValue { get; private set; }
    public int number 
    {
        set
        {
            NumberValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in test

```
var testMock = new FakeTestInterface();
var controller = new Controller(testMock);
controller.Initialize(); 
Assert.AreEqual(testMock.NumberValue, 3);
```

All mocking frameworks was designed to make our life easier, because we don't need to write own "fake" implementation.
When you faces problems with mocking frameworks - write your own mock object